# How to print 3 lists in different lines each seperated by a tab-space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 3 lists,

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']
```

The output I am trying is,

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying it?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Please post your attempts, it's easy for us but we need to see work on your part!

Comment: BTW, you could simply do `print('\n'.join([' '.join([x[i] for i in range(len(x))]) for x in [a,b,c]]))`.

Comment: If you're looking for more guidance, first try to write a function that prints one item, then it get it print one list, and finally, make a small adjustment so that your program prints all three lists.

Comment: @Zedaiq, it is working for you ?

Comment: Hello all, sorry for the delay, I've got it solved by using l = (a,b,c) l = np.transpose(l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ungolfed version -))

```
def list_to_str(lst):
    return " ".join(lst)

def handle_multi_lists (*lsts):
    return "\n".join(list_to_str(l) for l in lsts)

a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']

print(handle_multi_lists(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**zip**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) method in python to combine multiple list:

EX:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']

for i in zip(a, b, c):
    print " ".join(i)

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . I am also attach the screenshot of the output.

```
a = ['1','2','3']
b = ['4','5','6']
c = ['7','8','9']

for i in range(0,3):
  print(a[i] + "\t" + b[i] + "\t" + c[i])
  print("\n")
```

[image]

Comment: yes (y) it depend on you how you take it !

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list comprehension` in order to achieve your requirement.

Since your `lists` should have same length property, you can use a `for` loop until reach `range(len(list[0]))`

```
list = [a, b, c]
print([' '.join([elem[i] for i in range(len(list[0]))]) for elem in list])
```